# OutOfRangeException with Parallel.For

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

Ok, so I have a program that works ok. Inside of it there is a for loop that can be parallelized. So I used `Parallel.For` to do so. It worked ok one or two times, but the other times there's following exception:

> Unspecified error One or more errors occurred

No further information, just this helpful message. Anyone has any idea what might be happening?

Edit: Ok, So I nailed it down to an out of range exception. Turns out I was accessing array elements before initializing them, which seems like a race condition.
I had this:

```
 Parallel.For(0, 4, (i, state) =>
        {
            levelTwoPermutationObjects.Add(new permutationObject());
            levelTwoPermutationObjects[i].element = number;
            levelTwoPermutationObjects[i].DoThings();
         });
```

Which was making the second and third lines access an element that apparently didn't yet exist. I moved the element initialier out of the parallel loop (so that the array is initialized before being accessed), and now it works.

The iterations were almost independent of each other, except on that Add() part, that obviously depended if there was another element before it or not.

Comment: You should insert a break and step through each line of the method the thread runs and see where it throws an exception. The information you supplied isn't really going to be enough to help you.

Comment: This must be an `AggregateException` which has some helpful properties, namly `InnerException` and `InnerExceptions`. Please add these exceptions and their message to the question - otherwise your question is unanswerable...

Comment: Please do not edit the answer into the question. Post a self-answer. This is aa Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: Even though this question is in a bad shape atm, I would really like to reopen this question as it has a good base problem to work with. Please enhance your answer and I will vote for to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am risking a shot in the dark: `levelTwoPermutationObjects` is not thread-safe (ie being a `List<T>`). You should instead use collections of the namespace `System.Collections.Generic.Concurrent`, like `ConcurrentBag<T>` (as there's no thread-safe version of `List<T>`), as you are suffering a Race condition (please see [the example here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example)) with the [`.Add`-call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9cc11588bffd57c1) (read without write operations are ok within multithreading):

```
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}
```

Also see [the remarks at the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

If you are not willing or unable to adapt the type of `levelTwoPermutationObjects` you can also utilize a `lock`-statement like (**DANGER DO NOT USE - just for demo**):

```
var @lock = new object();
Parallel.For(0, 4, (i, state) =>
{
    lock (@lock)
    {
        levelTwoPermutationObjects.Add(new permutationObject());
        levelTwoPermutationObjects[i].element = number;
        levelTwoPermutationObjects[i].DoThings();
    }
 });
```

But this will make the `Parallel.For`-call useless. You should in fact adapt your code like (if I interpreted your code correctly):

```
var @lock = new object();
Parallel.For(0, 4, (i, state) =>
{
    var permutationObject = new permutationObject
    {
        element = number
    };
    permutationObject.DoThings();
    lock (@lock)
    {
        levelTwoPermutationObjects.Add(permutationObject);
    }
 });
```

If `.DoThings()` of `permutationObject` is a long running operation, you should fire off and forget the call with eg `Task.Run` instead of waiting for the result to proceed with the `.Add`-call.

Otherwise you can transform your processing chain into a seeding-process that adds elements to the collection (which should be a short running operation) and a processing-process (where each iteration can be a long running operation) to avoid a Race condition by only doing reads after sequential writes, like:

```
var levelTwoPermutationObjects = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
                                           .Select(arg => new permutationObject
                                                          {
                                                              element = number
                                                          })
                                           .ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(levelTwoPermutationObjects,
                 permutationObject => permutationObject.DoThings());
```

Comment: What about adding the elements to the list before, in a normal loop, and then keep the assignment and the levelTwoPermutationObjects[i].DoThings(); inside the parallel for? Is there anything wrong with that, besides using the non thread safe list?

Comment: This will add 2 items to the collection `basePermutationObjects` - what should be wrong with that? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, this posted the comment prematurely. It's fixed now

Comment: It will fail to a certain degree of possibility (that's the catch with multithreaded programming), as adding an item with `.Add(T)` to a `List<T>` is no atomic operation (it will internally check the underlying array and expand it if needed and then add the item), hence being a race condition.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure I understand why it's a race condition. I mean, each element is added sequentially. Only after they are each one on their place they are changed and accessed in multithreading. At which point exactly can the race condition happen?

Comment: They are added by `Parallel.For`. Have a look at the examples at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example and then have a look at the source at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9cc11588bffd57c1 - You will spot a non-atomic operation.

Comment: Yes, but what if I add the items in a normal for loop and keep the assignement and the DoThings() method inside the parallel loop? Doesn't that solve it??

Comment: @user3742604 That is exactly what I was suggesting with "transforming your processing chain". Besides, I would then utilize `Parallel.ForEach` instead.

Comment: @user3742604 You are welcome. I've also added an example for such a transformation.

Comment: You mention only doing the reads after the writes. However, each DoThings() method alters the contents of the respective levelTwoPermutationObject. There shouldn't be anything wrong with that right? Since each one are independent from one another?

Comment: `.DoThings()` should not touch the collection `levelTwoPermutatinObjects`. Can there be any problems with `.DoThings()`? Yes, if the code in this method isn't thread safe internally (accessing a shared register), like calling `.Add()` of another list. If it does only calculations on the own instance (which is independent from any other object), there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ok, got it. .DoThings() only performs calculations and alterations on its own levelTwoPermutatinObjects, based on its own internal set values, so everything should indeed work fine. Thanks again!